# SQL grouping same names

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've a table like this:

```
HotelName   HotelID  
Palace1        1       
Palace2        1        
Palace2        1        
Palace3        1       
Palace1        1        
Palace2        2        
Palace4        2        
Palace1        2        
Palace2        2      
Palace1        2
```

**EDIT:**
SOrry,I couldnt explain myself correctly.I've edited the table and now According to this table I want to group rows according to hotelName no matter what is rezervation date.Is there anyone to help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `having` to add conditions to your groups.

```
select HotelName
from your_table
group by HotelName
having count(HotelID) >= 5
```

Comment: could you edit your answer according to it ? Sorry for missunderstanding.

Comment: I updated my answer. If this is not what you want then please add the expected output of your example to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT HotelName, HotelID FROM Table GROUP BY HotelName, HotelID HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```